# How can I retain insertion order of a nested Perl hash and using clone?

Tags: perl

I am using IxHash to remember the insertion order of a hash. but when using clone to copy a hash i get an empty hash.

```
use strict;
use Switch;
use Data::Dumper;
use Clone qw(clone);
use Tie::Autotie 'Tie::IxHash';

our %h_basic_values;
my $t = tie our(%h_inner_hash), "Tie::IxHash";
my $t1 = tie our(%h_inner_hash1) , "Tie::IxHash";

%h_inner_hash = (
'in_1' => 'val_1',
'in_2' => 'val_2',
'in_3' => 'val_3'
);

%h_inner_hash1 = (
'innnn_1' => 'vallll_1',
'innnn_2' => 'vallll_2',
'innnn_3' => 'vallll_3',
);

$h_inner_hash{in_4}{inn_1} = "vall_1";
$h_inner_hash{in_4}{inn_2} = "vall_2";
$h_inner_hash{in_4}{inn_3} = "vall_3";
$h_inner_hash{in_4}{inn_4} = "vall_4";
$h_inner_hash{in_4}{inn_5}{innn_1} = 'valll_1';
$h_inner_hash{in_4}{inn_5}{innn_2} = "valll_2";
$h_inner_hash{in_4}{inn_5}{innn_3} = "valll_3";
$h_inner_hash{in_4}{inn_5}{innn_4} = "valll_4";

$h_inner_hash{in_4}{inn_5}{innn_5} = clone(\%h_inner_hash1);
print Dumper(\%h_inner_hash);
```

in $h_inner_hash{in_4}{inn_5}{innn_5} i am getting an empty hash.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a problem with Clone, or with the fact that `%h_inner_hash1` is tied. It's a [limitation of `Tie::Autotie`](http://p3rl.org/Tie::Autotie#BUGS). From its perldoc:

> ### BUGS
>
> [...]
>
> #### Assigning a reference
>
> In the Tie::IxHash example, you cannot
>   do:
>
> ```
> $hash{jeff} = {
>   age => 22,
>   lang => 'Perl',
>   brothers => 3,
>   sisters => 4,
> };
> ```
>
> because that creates a hash reference,
>   not an object of Tie::IxHash. This
>   hash reference ends up being destroyed
>   anyway, and replaced with a
>   Tie::IxHash object that points to an
>   empty hash.

As a means round it, you could manually copy `%h_inner_hash1` key-by-key:

```
$h_inner_hash{in_4}{inn_5}{innn_5}{$_} = $h_inner_hash1{$_} for keys %h_inner_hash1;
```

or you could manually tie each layer of the hash to Tie::IxHash rather than using Tie::Autotie.

Comment: Just to be clear - the quoted section from POD is under **BUGS** heading.